# Parsing string and number with regex separated with space

Tags: regex, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column with values that include currency and value. Base variant is `'USD 100000000.00'` I have to separate values and currency to different columns.

In some cases one of them is absent so string looks like `' 100000000.00'` - starting with `space` or `'USD '` - finishing with `space`.

Works correct:

```
SELECT to_number(regexp_substr('USD ','[^ ]+', 1, 2)) as val from dual;
```

Empty val:

```
SELECT to_number(regexp_substr(' 100000000','[^ ]+', 1, 2)) as val from dual;
```

Empty val as well (correct):

```
SELECT to_number(regexp_substr('USD 100000000.00','[^ ]+', 1, 2)) as val from dual;
```

How can I get numeric value for this case `' 100000000'`?

Comment: Maybe all you need is to match the last non-whitespace chunk? `SELECT to_number(regexp_substr(' 100000000','[^ ]+$')) as val from dual`?

Comment: Well, if you need to also pre-validate the input, try `regexp_substr('USD 100000000','^(USD)?\s*(\d*\.?\d+)$', 1,1, NULL, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regular expression `^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$` to match:

- the start of the string; then
- zero-or-more non-whitespace characters; then
- one-or-more whitespace characters; then
- zero-or-more non-whitespace characters; then
- the end-of-string

And then extract the 1st and 2nd capture groups as the currency and amount respectively:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         your_currency_string,
         '^(\S*)\s*(\S*)$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1                          -- 1st capture group
       ) AS currency,
       TO_NUMBER(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           your_currency_string,
           '^(\S*)\s*(\S*)$',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           2                          -- 2nd capture group
         )
       ) AS amount
FROM   your_table
```

If you want to be more restrictive on your regular expression then you could use:

```
^(\S*)\s+(([1-9]\d*|0)?\.?\d{0,2})$
```

Which would match numbers with, optionally, up to 2 decimal places and no leading zeros on the integer part (i.e. `0` and `1000` are allowed but `00` and `01000` are not - but you could just use `(\d*\.?\d{0,2})$` if you don't want this restriction).

You could also just match the start and end of the string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_currency_string, '^(\S*)' ) AS currency,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_currency_string, '(\S*)$' ) ) AS amount
FROM   your_table
```